# Get available locations for a service in Azure subscription

Tags: python, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I writing a code in python and I need to find a way to get a list of all available locations for a specific service.
For example, all locations where I can create storage accounts, SQL servers, etc.
Is there a way to it programmatically in python?

Comment: Is it ok if I point you to REST API documentation and equivalent class in Python SDK?

Comment: Ideally, I'm looking for python code that can do this but this would also help and be a great start!

Comment: Unfortunately not that much conversant with python. Provided an answer though. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Each resource in Azure has a resource provider (e.g. For storage accounts, the provider is `Microsoft.Storage`). Resource provider REST API exposes the list of locations where a kind of resource in a resource provider can be created.

You can read more about the API here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/providers/get (look for `ProviderResourceType` section on this page).

When I ran the above REST API against my subscription and `Microsoft.Storage` resource provider, I got the following response for `storageAccounts` resource type and locations:

```
  "resourceTypes": [
    {
      "resourceType": "storageAccounts",
      "locations": [
        "East US", "East US 2", "West US", "West Europe",
        "East Asia", "Southeast Asia", "Japan East",
        "Japan West", "North Central US", "South Central US",
        "Central US", "North Europe", "Brazil South",
        "Australia East", "Australia Southeast", "South India",
        "Central India", "West India", "Canada East",
        "Canada Central", "West US 2", "West Central US",
        "UK South", "UK West", "Korea Central", "Korea South",
        "France Central", "Australia Central", "South Africa North",
        "UAE North", "Switzerland North", "Germany West Central",
        "Norway East"
      ],
```

I am not conversant with Python SDK but I believe the equivalent class for this would be [`ProviderResourceType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-resource/azure.mgmt.resource.resources.v2019_10_01.models.providerresourcetype?view=azure-python) class.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for. This gives me all 33 locations but for SQL, for example, I can create servers only in 17 locations. The other 16 just throws an exception that I can't create servers in this region at this moment.

Comment: `The other 16 just throws an exception that I can't create servers in this region at this moment.` - This could probably be because Azure is running with some capacity reserved for emergency services. I have seen many questions where users were not able to create resources. This is a temporary situation though.